# how to run simple php script from Daemon at CentOS?

Tags: php, bash, daemon

I need to run a very simple php script every second in CentOS. Someone told me I should use Daemon to run my php script every second in the background. Is there any guide how to do it? I know nothing about Daemon and when I search from the internet, it looks very complicated.

Anyone can help?

This is my current code. It keep running when I run : php -q /check_status.php

But when I disconnect to the server, it stops running. What should I do to keep it running?

## !/usr/bin/php -q

```
<?php

require_once "System/Daemon.php";
$daemon_options = array("appName" => "channel_usage");
System_Daemon::setoptions($daemon_options);

System_Daemon::start();

while (true)
{
//some php code
}

sleep(1);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command with nohup infront of it, this will have it continue executing even if your session ends.

Example:

```
nohup ping google.com
```

This will keep pinging google even if you close your ssh session.

Or you can schedule a cronjob by doing the following (change the command to your own needs):

```
echo "* * * * * /path/to/script.sh" >> /etc/crontab
```